# How to create different layout for Galaxy S4 and Nexus 4

Tags: android

I am using "layout-sw360dp" for both Galaxy S4 and Nexus 4 devices but in my screen displaying some space on Galaxy S4. so can i make different layout for both Galaxy S4 and Nexus 4. if it is possible then please give me the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per other answers one device is `640 x 360 dp` and the other `640 x 384 dp`.

You **don't** want to make a different layout for them, because you will sooner or later see a device `640 x 372 dp` or `640 x 388 dp`.

Instead make your layout elastic and don't hardcode pixels (density independent pixels can also be badly hardcoded).

Comment: this really isn't the best answer...I'm sure you can think of a ton of situations where you'll need to get pixel perfect.  Google needs to be able to support every device to the pixel for games and graphics heavy apps.  I totally agree with the strategy to make everything elastic, however that will not always work for every developer's situation.  I've tried sw360dp-long-land for the Nexus 4, but that didn't work, so this is still a valid issue.

Comment: Even more to the point, the S3 and Nexus4 are both sw360dp, but it seems like floating buttons are about 12dp off when using the same layout folder.  So what would be your suggestion for something like this, if you had no other choice?

Answer (score 8):

For Galaxy s4 use `layout-xxhdpi`

For Nexus 4 use `layout-xhdpi`

```
Galaxy S4 -- 1080 x 1920 pixels -- 5.0" -- 441 ppi -- xxhdpi
Nexus 4   -- 1280 x  768 pixels -- 4.7" -- 320 ppi -- xhdpi
```

You have to make different images to fit to the resolution of these devices

Comment: Have any solutions for Galaxy S3 vs Nexus 4 (720x1280 vs 768x1280)?  I've tried sw360dp-long and that didn't work.

Comment: use the sw384dp for the Nexus 4 if you need to hone in on that one device/resolution.

Comment: thanks for info of s4 xxhdpi and nexus 4 xhdpi...even nexus 5 is xxhdpi

Answer (score 5):

ok here goes... 
for reference

1. this is older layout folder naming conventions but you get the point.
2. You must convert everything to mdpi to go into the following buckets.
3. buckets for layouts are :
   xlarge 960 x720 min
   large 640 x480 min
   normal 470 x 320 min
   small 426x 320 min
4. scaling ratio 
   3:4:6:8:12
   this means that you must multiple ldpi * 3/4 to go from ldpi to mdpi
   and you must multiple mdpi * 4/6 to go from mdpi to hdpi
   and you must multiple hdpi * 6/8 to go from hdpi to xhdpi
   and you must multiple xhdpi *  8/12 to go from xhdpi to xxhdpi

so to answer the question....

s4 is xxhdpi which means the scaling ratio is 4/12 or 1/3. This means that you have to convert from xxhdpi to mdpi to place in a layout folder properly.
so 1080 * 1/3 = 360
and 1920 * 1/3 = 640
so this would place it in a normal layout folder

nexus 4 is xhdpi which means the scaling ratio is 4/8 or 1/2. 4 This means that you have to convert from xhdpi to mdpi to place in a layout folder properly.
so 1280 * 1/2 = 640
and 768 * 1/2 = 384
so this would place it in a normal layout folder as well.

ok, so this doesn't quite cut it because they are different resolutions.  we can make up folders with the new naming conventions. for example the smallest width for the s4 is 360 while the smallest width for the nexus 4 is 384.  so folders could be sw360dp and sw384dp.
you could also name the folder layout-xxhdpi which would catch the s4 but not the nexus 4

be aware: Just to throw another one out there what if you had an s3 as well.  that would go in the sw360dp folder as well.  so I guess you would have to differ between them as well.  if you used layout-xxhdpi above then you could use sw360dp here and sw384dp above as well.  cover them all.
thanks

Comment: sw-360dp has higher preference then xxhdpi hence if we have both folders S4 and S3 will take from sw360dp only.

Comment: I say they need different folders so why the downvote?  and I say to be aware!  and an explanation why to be aware.

Comment: why don't use sw360dp-xxhdpi and sw360dp-xhdpi?

Answer (score 0):

Both these phones have **different screen size and resolution** ,
 that leads to different density as well .

As per my knowledge -

> Galaxy s4 has 1080 x 1920 pixels, 5.0 inches (~441 ppi pixel density).

And

> Nexus 4 has 1280 x 768 pixels, 4.7 inches (320 ppi ).

You will have to design the layouts (and images as well ) according to the phones specifications.

Answer (score 0):

for nexus 4 use below layout.

layout-sw360dp

both galaxy s3 and nexus 4 have same layouts.

Comment: I think nexus 4 has a `normal` screen size and not a `large`